# Using directive in App_Code .cs file directed towards DLL in a subfolder inside /bin

Tags: asp.net, iis, shared, bin, app-code

:)

I'm trying to make some kind of shared code "repository" so I don't have to copy the files to around 20 projects or something I'm having to maintain.

Environment: Win7, IIS 7, VS2010, ASP.NET 4.0 Website (not Web Application).

I've set my directory structure like this:

```
App_Code
  - Shared.Web (virtual dir -> C:\Apps\Shared\Shared.Web)
  - BasePage.cs <- this one has problems :(
Bin
  - Shared.Bin (virtual dir -> C:\Apps\Shared\Shared.Bin)
    - Shared.Web.dll
    - Shared.Web.pdb
MasterPage.aspx
MasterPage.cs
Default.aspx
Default.cs
Web.config
```

Everything works fine on the ASPX files, but the BasePage.cs has problems, because it has an

```
using SharedWeb;
```

Which should work but it doesn't, stating that the assembly or namespace isn't found. I've set my web.config this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="Bin;Bin\Shared.Bin;" />
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="SharedWeb" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/Apps/Shared/Shared.Bin/Shared.Web.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

Nothing fancy as you can see.

Reference: http://warren.chinalle.com/2008/10/14/multiple-bin-folders-aspnet/

Now, the question: Any ideas on how to make the BasePage.cs file can get the assembly as an using directive for the assembly inside Bin/Shared.Bin?

Thanks in advance!

- DARKGuy

Comment: You have `Shared.Web` throughout your config and file names, but your `using` statement has `SharedWeb` (without a period). Which is it?

Comment: SharedWeb is on the DLL file, it has lots of classes but all of them have "namespace SharedWeb" and such. Assembly name is just Shared though.

Comment: Shared.Web is the DLL name, yeah I know confusing, I could do some refactoring and change the names, but I'd have to see first if what I need to do is possible

Comment: I don't think the `privatePath` on the `probing` element will accept a virtual directory; wouldn't you need to specify the full physical path instead?

Comment: @RichardDeeming: Nope, just tried and that didn't work. Neither only the path Bin/Shared.Bin, or changing slashes to backslashes, or absolute, or relative. Error says: "The type or namespace name 'SharedWeb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" in BasePage.cs :(

Comment: No ideas anyone? I hate bumping...